# phonegap android inappbrowser back button only navbar

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

it seems that there is no way to config to show the back button only in inAppBrowser narbar of phonegap, is there any alternative solution?

Such as 

1. show a jquerymobile nav bar at the top of the app, and the inappbrowser show in the rest place of the app

2. create a back button at the top of the webpage manually of target url (remote url/webpage)

3. use insertcss to hide the url bar and arrow?

is there any other ways to create back button only for the inAppBrowser?